# How to write up and report a Bayesian analysis?

Tags: bayesian, reporting

Bayesian Estimation Supersedes the t-Test for **John K. Kruschke** is one of the most important papers that I had read explaining how to run the Bayesian analysis and how to make the plots.

> But the most important point is how to report the results from the plots to write up a paper?

My question here is: Do you know any model paper with a clear guideline explaining how to report the results of Bayesian analysis or if someone can help me to report the results from the following figures (The figures are a comparison between the means for two groups):

[image]

Comment: Have you read Kruschke's ["How to report a Bayesian analysis: Teaching why"](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/how-to-report-bayesian-analysis.html)?

Comment: @jO. Sure!, I had. Actually, this is from the first edition of his book and unfortunately the presented information about how to report the results is blurry. I hope he will present a clear guideline in the second edition of his book (will be available in the mid of Novemeber)

Comment: Mike McCarthy is an Ecologist and a frequent user of Bayesian models. Check out his publications and maybe also his book [Bayesian methods for Ecology](http://mickresearch.wordpress.com/micks-publications/)